# How to restart failed Chunks - Spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I am writing Spring batch for chunk processing.
I have Single Job and Single Step. Within that Step I have Chunks which are dynamically sized.

> SingleJob -> SingleStep -> chunk_1..chunk_2..chunk_3...so on

Following is a case I am trying to implement,

If Today I ran a Job and only `chunk_2` failed and rest of chunks ran successfully. Now Tomorrow I want to run/restart ONLY failed chunks i.e. in this case `chunk_2`. (I don't want to run whole Job/Step/Other successfully completed Chunks)

I see Spring batch allow to store metadata and using that it helps to restart Jobs. but I did not get if it is possible to restart specific chunk as discuss above.

Am I missing any concept or if it is possible then any pseudo code/theoretical explanation or reference will help.

I appreciate your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how Spring Batch works in a restart scenario, it will continue where it left off in the previous failed run.

So in your example, if the in the first run `chunk1` has been correctly processed and `chunk2` failed, the next job execution will restart at `chunk2`.

Comment: Is it possible that if chunk2 failed but allow rest chunks to get execute. ie skip error chunk and continue execution.

Comment: That's possible using a fault-tolerant chunk-oriented step. But in this case, it is not a failure anymore, the step will skip a chunk and continue processing next chunks until completion. The status of the step would be "completed" (with skips, you can create a custom exit status BTW, here is an example: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/common/SkipCheckingListener.java#L41). In this case, it is up to you to figure out how to re-process skipped items.